# How to loop to dictionary in dictionary to organize data from CSV in specified way

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, multiple-columns

I made a script that:

-takes data from CSV file -sort it by same values in first column of data file
-instert sorted data in specifield line in different template text file
-save the file in as many copies as there are different values in first column from data file This picture below show how it works:

[image: how program works]

But there are two more things I need to do. When in separate files as showed above, there are some of the same values from second column of the data file, then this file should insert value from third column instead of repeating the same value from second column. On the picture below I showed how it should look like:

[image]

What I also need is to add somewhere separeted value of first column from data file by "_".

There is datafile:

```
111_0,3005,QWE
111_0,3006,SDE
111_0,3006,LFR
111_1,3005,QWE
111_1,5345,JTR
112_0,3103,JPP
112_0,3343,PDK
113_0,2137,TRE
113_0,2137,OMG
```

and there is code i made:

```
import shutil
 
with open("data.csv") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    contents = contents.splitlines()
 
values_per_baseline = dict()
 
for line in contents:
    key = line.split(',')[0]
    values = line.split(',')[1:]
    if key not in values_per_baseline:
        values_per_baseline[key] = []
    values_per_baseline[key].append(values)
 
for file in values_per_baseline.keys():
    x = 3
    shutil.copyfile("of.txt", (f"of_%s.txt" % file))
    filename = f"of_%s.txt" % file
    for values in values_per_baseline[file]:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
            contents.insert(x, '      o = ' + values[0] + '\n          ' + 'a = ' + values[1] +'\n')
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            contents = "".join(contents)
            f.write(contents)
            f.close()
```

I have been trying to make something like a dictionary of dictionaries of lists but I can't implement it in correct way to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I get this error:

```
    contents.insert(x, '      o = ' + values[0] + '\n          ' + 'a = ' + values[3] +'\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Let's think where this error is coming from. It is an `IndexError` on a list. The only list used on this line is `values` so that seems like a good place to start looking.

To debug, you can consider adding something like this before the line that is spitting the error:

```
            print(values)
            print(values[0])
            print(values[3])
```

which gives

```
['3005', 'QWE']
3005
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qqq.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(values[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So the problem is with `values[3]`, which makes sense since `len(values)==2` and so the indices need to be `0` and `1`. If we change `values[3]` to `values[1]` then I think you get what you want. e.g.:

```
$ cat of_111_0.txt
line
line
line
      o = 3006
          a = LFR
      o = 3006
          a = SDE
      o = 3005
          a = QWE
line
line
line
line
line
```

To get to the next step in your problem, I would suggest you change your first loop to:

```
for line in contents:
    key = line.split(',')[0]
    values = line.split(',')[1:]
    if key not in values_per_baseline:
        values_per_baseline[key] = {}
    if values[0] not in values_per_baseline[key]:
        values_per_baseline[key][values[0]] = values[1]
    else:
        values_per_baseline[key][values[0]] += '<COMMA>' + values[1]
```

That gives your dictionary to be:

```
{'111_0': {'3005': 'QWE', 
           '3006': 'SDE<COMMA>LFR'}, 
 '111_1': {'3005': 'QWE', 
           '5345': 'JTR'}, 
 '112_0': {'3103': 'JPP', 
           '3343': 'PDK'}, 
 '113_0': {'2137': 'TRE<COMMA>OMG'}}
```

Then when writing to the file, you would need to change your loop to:

```
        for key in values_per_baseline[file]:
            contents.insert(x, f'{6*sp}o = {key}\n{10*sp}a = {values_per_baseline[file][key]}\n')
```

And your file now looks like:

```
line
line
line
      o = 3006
          a = SDE<COMMA>LFR
      o = 3005
          a = QWE
line
line
line
line
line
```

**Other things you could do**

Now, there are a couple of things you can do to streamline your code while keeping it readable.*

- On lines 10 and 11, there is no need to use `line.split` twice. Just add a line that has something like `split_line = line.split(',')` and then have `key = split_line[0]` and `values = split_line[1:]`. (You could do away with `key` and `values` all together and just reference `split_line[0]` and `split_line[1]` but that would make your code less readable.
- On line 17, you are defining `x` in *every* loop. Just take it out of the loop.
- On lines 12 and 13, you are first using `(f"of_%s.txt" % file)` and then defining it in a file on the next line. Suggest you define `filename` first and then just have `shutil.copyfile("of.txt", filename)`. Also, you are using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) incorrectly. You could just write `filename = f"of_{file}.txt"`.
- On line 23, you could change your `insert` command to an f-string (if you find it more readable). For example: `contents.insert(x, f'{6*sp}o = {values[0]}\n{10*sp}a = {values[1]}\n')`
- At the end, in your `for values in values_per_baseline.keys()` loop, you are opening and closing files way more than you need to. You can reorder your operations:

```
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for values in values_per_baseline[file]:
            contents.insert(x, '      o = ' + values[0] + '\n          ' + 'a = ' + values[1] +'\n')
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        contents = "".join(contents)
        f.write(contents)
        f.close()
```

*For a short script like this, I would argue that making sure it is readable is more important than making sure it is efficient, since you will want to be able to come back in 3 weeks or 3 years and understand what you did. For that reason, I would also recommend you comment what you did.

Comment: Thanks a lot for many tips. In my code this values[3] was a typo actually, it should stayed as values[1], so it was not the biggest problem I am dealing with. Basically the idea was to write it like that:
If second column value from CSV file is not the same as in previous row then:
Write in file: "O = <value from second column> A = <value from third column>"
If second column value from CSV file is the same as in previous row then:
Write in file: "A = <value from third column>"
As I showed on second picture, where some values from third row a separated by <COMMA>

Comment: Well, I guess that is why you should check your code before you post it! Give me a couple of minutes to update...